# Better solution for finding unique visitors

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am using the following query for finding the number of unique visitors from one of my table for each day. But this is affecting the performance. Can anyone suggest a better solution for this. My current query is :

```
SELECT t.date,COUNT(DISTINCT t.uID) as unique_clicks FROM table_name t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM table_name t2
        WHERE
            t2.uID = t.uID
            AND t2.date < (t.date)
    )
GROUP BY t.date
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: Set up a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: Why do you need `NOT EXISTS` predicate? Why not just count with a `group by`: `SELECT t.date,COUNT(DISTINCT t.uID) as unique_clicks FROM table_name t GROUP BY t.date`?

Comment: What do you mean by unique visitors for each day. Do you mean if a person has visited in the previous day he should be excluded?

Comment: @raheelshan Yes he should be excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT
  t.date, COUNT(DISTINCT t.uID) as unique_clicks
FROM
  table_name t LEFT JOIN table_name t1
  ON t.uID=t2.uID AND t2.date < t.date
WHERE
  t2.uID is NULL
GROUP BY t.date
```

I think that a join should be faster than an EXISTS clause in this particular situation. Or if I understand the logic correctly, also this:

```
SELECT min_date, COUNT(*) as unique_clicks
FROM (
  SELECT
    t.uID, min(t.date) min_date
  FROM
    table_name t
  GROUP BY
    t.uID
  ) s
GROUP BY min_date
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4de3f/1).